# Le rapace « Autour des palombes ». Sens du terme

Tags: sens, zoologie

Bonjour, on a des pigeons voyageurs, et parfois avec des colombophiles français je parle des rapaces qui peuvent tuer les pigeons.

Un de ces rapaces s'appelle « Autour des palombes ».

Palombes veulent dire les pigeons qui se trouvent dans les bois, ça je comprends. Mais le mot « autour ». Ça signifie que le rapace vole autour des pigeons, en proximité ? C'est un adjectif ? Si autour est un nom, je ne le connais pas.

Merci de votre aide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[**Autour**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autour)* est ici un nom commun, en l'occurrence un nom d'oiseau ;-) qui vient du latin ***[accipiter](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accipiter)***, rien à voir avec l'adverbe *[autour](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autour/1)* qui est une agglutination de *au* et de *tour*.